# Should we close these old "Subjective" & "List" questions or make them community wikis?

Tags: discussion, scope

These two questions were asked back in android.SE's infancy:

1. [Can you recommend some alternative keyboards for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56/can-you-recommend-some-alternative-keyboards-for-android)
2. [What is the best alternative to the stock camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-the-stock-camera-app-closed)

They were both flagged today as too subjective and I believe those flaggers were right.  Considering how long they've been around and how much interaction they've gotten do you think they should be closed or made community wikis?

I actually already closed the second one, which was my question.

Comment: I'm tempted to open a Meta question questioning the mental stability of our mods, after I saw one talking to himself in comments...

Comment: I am familiar with that mod, and there is no need to question it.  He is not stable.

Comment: Relevant, and probably why people have started flagging these: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Answer (score 2):

Probably some combination of both; the old historical questions on Stack Overflow (such as "favorite programming cartoon" etc) had the same issue.

In general **the ones that have genuinely useful and semi-timeless information**  should be retained, but capped in rep and answers. Otherwise they grow infinitely, which is not useful..

Answer (score 0):

Closed.

Although I don't think we should spend our time hunting them down. If they bubble back to the front page because they were answered again or otherwise bumped and we spot them, then we should act on them. (Or, of course, if someone flags them.)